# javascript: How to add a column to a table in greasemonkey/prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I want to enhance a html page using Greasemonkey and javascript.

It is my goal: Add an extra cells after the last cell in each of  element of the table

The page is already using prototype (so prototype is available to us)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is add a cell in each row, correct? If that is the case:

Prototype.js:

```
$$("tr").each(function(tr){ 
    $(tr).insert('<td>Content of the new cell</td>') 
})
```

jQuery:

```
$("tr").append("<td>Content of the new cell</td>")
```

Comment: Why the function wrapper in the `.append` call?

Comment: No reason at all, i just copied the same example and forgot that in jQuery a string can be used for the append Method